# Azure Function Email Notification when error

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-functions

Is there a way to set up Email Notifications in Azure if an Azure Function fails on a given run?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you [JayaC-MSFT](https://learn.microsoft.com/answers/users/3083315/jayac-msft.html) posting your [suggestion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/99459/how-to-create-email-alert-for-failure-of-function.html) as an answer to help other community members.

"You may follow  [this](https://www.fourmoo.com/2020/02/19/how-to-configure-azure-function-app-notifications-for-errors/)  link to configure the email alert for your azure functions.

You may also check these links for step by step implementation :

http://www.mattruma.com/adventures-with-azure-functions-create-an-alert-from-app-insight-to-send-an-email-notification/

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/alerts-log

You'll receive a similar email :

[image]

Comment: perfect! thanks so much

Comment: Could you please re-write the answer here please? The link seems dead. =(

Comment: I think this answer is outdated, I guess one has to setup a `custom log search`, but I might be wrong